# Help with XPath syntax

Tags: xml, xpath, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am trying to get all the nodes under NewDataset all the 'Items' node. Could you please help.

Here is my xml and Xpath syntax.

```
string xpath = "/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/GetItemsResponse/getItemsResult/NewDataset";
XPathNodeIterator clItems = this.DataSources[listDS.GetItems].CreateNavigator().Select(xpath, NamespaceManager);
```

XML:

```
<dfs:myFields
  xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution"
  xmlns:ns3="http://test222.com/"
  xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2010-11-22T16:05:55"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <dfs:queryFields>
    <ns3:GetItems>
      <ns3:list1>test</ns3:list1>
    </ns3:GetItems>
  </dfs:queryFields>
  <dfs:dataFields>
    <GetItemsResponse xmlns="http://test222.com/">
      <GetItemsResult>
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
          <Items>
            <Clist>list1</Clist>
            <Title>test1</Title>
           </Items>
           <Items>
              <Clist>list2</Clist>
              <Title>test2</Title>
           </Items>
        </NewDataSet>
      </GetItemsResult>
    </GetItemsResponse>
  </dfs:dataFields>
</dfs:myFields>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set namespace (`http://test222.com/`) to `GetItemsResponse` and `GetItemsResult`

Fully qualified: `/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/ns3:GetItemsResponse/ns3:GetItemsResult/NewDataSet/Items`.

Answer (score 1):

this should be it:

```
//NewDataSet/Items
```

it returns all items.
in you case, should be

```
 string xpath = "//NewDataSet/Items";
```

Comment: For some reason I am not getting the items. Is my path correct? namespace etc.Please let me know.

Comment: have you managed the namespace well. the namesapce for items should be empty...because you have <NewDataSet xmlns="">.